# Workflow Manager security configuration issues?

Tags: workflow-manager, service-bus

I have been trying to install the Workflow Manager on our SharePoint farm. I verified that all services are running (Service Bus message broker, Service Bus Gateway, Windows Frabric Host Service and the Workflow Manager backend) and they do under a farm account that I specified.

However, when trying to access the Worfklow Manager site it returns the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ScopeInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/workflow/2012/xaml/activities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DefaultWorkflowConfiguration/>
    <Description>Root Scope</Description>
    <LastModified>2014-06-18T15:56:53.21</LastModified>
    <LastRevised>2014-06-18T15:56:53.21</LastRevised>
    <Path>/</Path>
        <SecurityConfigurations>
            <ScopedSecurityConfiguration i:type="WindowsSecurityConfiguration">
            <Name>Microsoft.Workflow.Management.Security.WindowsSecurityConfiguration</Name>
            <WorkflowAdminGroupName>BUILTIN\Administrators</WorkflowAdminGroupName></ScopedSecurityConfiguration>
        </SecurityConfigurations>
    <Status>Active</Status>
    </ScopeInfo>
```

What is the resolution for this? I have been going through Microsoft TechNet's articles but couldn't troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the XML that's mean your Installation & configuration of Workflow Manager is sucessfull.

Now next step is register the work. To register the wrokflow with sharepoint, use below technet.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588(v=office.15)#section4](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588%28v=office.15%29#section4)

After this, you have to validate it.
To validate the installation

- Add a user to your SharePoint site, and grant the user Site Designer
  permissions.
- Install SharePoint Designer 2013 and create a workflow based on the
  SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform.
- Run this workflow from the SharePoint user interface.